# How should we calculate the difference between the numbers in a sequence?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When we're given a sequence, for example,
$$ 1^{5^n}, 2^{5^n},3^{5^n}, \dots \ (n \in \mathbb{N}) $$

And we're asked to calculate the difference between the numbers in this sequence, how should we solve it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: So here $n$ is a constant, I see. Would wirte $(k+1)^{5^n}-k^{5^n}$ and wait for the need to do something else to actually manifest itself.

Comment: Agree with Gae. S's comment.  Alternative tool in your arsenal should be that for $$m ~\in ~\mathbb{Z^+}, ~(a^m - b^m) ~=~ (a - b) \times ~\left[\sum_{k = 0}^{(m-1)} ~a^{(m - 1 - k)}b^k\right].$$